# How to plot the CCDF in pgfplots?

Tags: pgfplots

I am trying to plot the complementary cumulative distribution function (CCDF) using pgfplots. I found this answer [Drawing cumulative distribution function for a discrete variable](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/198383/drawing-cumulative-distribution-function-for-a-discrete-variable) which plots only the CDF.

After reading the details in that answer I found this code `create col/expr={\pgfmathaccuma + \thisrow{f(x)}}` which as I understand calculates the cumulative sum of the row in f(x).

My problem is how to get the 1-CDF in this fourmla?

I tried using `create col/expr={1 - \pgfmathaccuma - \thisrow{f(x)}}` but it is wrong.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When using `create col/expr`, `\pgfmathaccuma` starts out being equal to 0. If you want to set a different starting value, use `create col/expr accum={<expression>}{<starting value>}`.

So in this case, you'd use `create col/expr accum={\pgfmathaccuma - \thisrow{f(x)}}{1}`.

Comment: Yes I found it finally thank you. Can you help me fix the marker because I obtain only horizontal lines without the dashed vertical lines nor the marker?