# How do I plot a Cumulative Distribution Function (CDF) of Discrete Numbers in LaTex Environment?

Tags: pgfplots, plot

The overall achievement vector of a person/household is designated by `x=(x_1 \cdots x_n)`. To demonstrate, imagine that there are five persons in a society with over all income `$25`, `$18`, `$15`, `$33`, `$31`. In this case `x=(25, 18, 15, 33, 31)` is a vector indicating the income of the society. 
As can be seen, ordering/ranking the overall achievement vector; in other words, ranking/ordering individuals or households by their achievements yields `(15, 18, 25, 31, 33)`.
The aim here is to plot the cumulative distribution function for `X`?  It is an excerpt my research Thesis - a Welfare Analysis approach in the Multidimensional Poverty Analysis domains!

```
\begin{axis}[
    clip=false,
    jump mark left,
    ymin=0,ymax=1,
    xmin=0, xmax=6,
    every axis plot/.style={very thick},
    discontinuous,
    table/create on use/cumulative distribution/.style={
        create col/expr={\pgfmathaccuma + \thisrow{f(x)}}   
    }
]
\addplot [red] table [y=cumulative distribution]{
P(x) f(x)
<15  0
15  1/5
18  2/5
25 3/5
31 4/5
33 1
};
\end{axis}
```

Comment: What is the question here? The text above looks like a textbook question for Economics ...

Comment: Dear Chistian, Not an economics question, yet I am constructing a methodology for my Ph.D. Thesis, the purpose is I want to write a cumulative distribution function of the above statement in Latex. Yet as failed and the error reported is "environment axis undefined".  Yet I am not sure if I have the appropriate mathematical equation as well. Please help.

Comment: The above statement is an excerpt from the Methodology part of my research. I started from that hoping that it may give background informatio to the underpinning purpose and the problem I encountered.

Comment: So you want to plot it, not write it. You need  `\usepackage{pgfplots}` for that plotting code.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Comment: By the way, I recommend reading the entire post you most likely got your code from: http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/198397/586 Note that if you look at the complete example at the end, there some stuff in the preamble that defines the `discontinous` style.

Comment: Dear @Holene thanks for the priceless information. My problem was addressed by @ Torbjørn T.  below. Apologies if my question was vague and amorphous!

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 7):

I have adjusted the following things to obtain the result below:

- The code for the key `discontinuous` is copied from [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/198397).
- The x and y ranges didn't fit; I adjusted them to

  ```
  ymin=0,ymax=3.5, xmin=14,xmax=35,
  ```
- Currently the first column is taken as the x values, hence "<15" doesn't work. I replaced it by 14, the smallest value of the range.
- I added the upper bound of the x range (35) to the table, such that the last accumulated value is also drawn.

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=2mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\makeatletter
\long\def\ifnodedefined#1#2#3{%
    \@ifundefined{pgf@sh@ns@#1}{#3}{#2}%
}

\pgfplotsset{
    discontinuous/.style={
    scatter,
    scatter/@pre marker code/.code={
        \ifnodedefined{marker}{
            \pgfpointdiff{\pgfpointanchor{marker}{center}}%
             {\pgfpoint{0}{0}}%
             \ifdim\pgf@y>0pt
                \tikzset{options/.style={mark=*, fill=white}}
                \draw [densely dashed,blue] (marker-|0,0) -- (0,0);
                \draw plot [mark=*] coordinates {(marker-|0,0)};
             \else
                \tikzset{options/.style={mark=none}}
             \fi
        }{
            \tikzset{options/.style={mark=none}}        
        }
        \coordinate (marker) at (0,0);
        \begin{scope}[options]
    },
    scatter/@post marker code/.code={\end{scope}}
    }
}

\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    clip=false,
    jump mark left,
    ymin=0,ymax=3.5,
    xmin=14,xmax=35,
    xlabel={income},
    ylabel={cumulative distribution},
    every axis plot/.style={very thick},
    discontinuous,
    table/create on use/cumulative distribution/.style={
        create col/expr={\pgfmathaccuma + \thisrow{f(x)}}   
    }
]
\addplot [red] table [y=cumulative distribution]{
P(x) f(x)
14   0
15  1/5
18  2/5
25 3/5
31 4/5
33 1
35 0
};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: See http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/198397/586 for the likely definition of `discontinous`.

Comment: @TorbjørnT. Thanks, I've adapted the answer.

Comment: @ Torbjørn T.                                                                               Hello, Sir,  I thank you so much for your kind effective assistance. It perfectly serves the purpose and my challenges are simplified.
Big apologies for bothering you, yet, I have some more questions.
1. While the min. and max.  values of the CDF and hence the "y"-value are supposed to be (0) and (1) respectively,  how do we justify values greater than 1 (like 2, 3).  
2.  Can we have alternative color for the CDF step functions?  horizontal "red" and the vertical (jump) "blue". 

I thank you!

Comment: Plus, How do I write(include) income in the horizontal (x-axis) and Cumulative Distribution in the vertical (Y-axis)?

Comment: @HailaiWeldeslassie I have added labels to the axes and coloured the vertical lines in blue. What do you mean by *justifying y-values bigger than 1*? If you accumulate the values, the y-values may become arbitrarily large. Calculate the sums to check.

Comment: @gernot  Thank so much for your kind assistance. Big apologies for not responding swiftly owing to problems beyond my control. To explicate my last question on the 'y'-value, it's a probability of CDF  and the maximum value must add up to 1. Thus, could it be possible to make some adjustment taking this into account. 

Other issues were addressed sufficiently and fit the purpose perfectly.
I am very appreciative in advance for your usual priceless assistance. I look forward to hearing from you shortly as I am still stuck with the above mentioned problem. 

Thank you!

Comment: @HailaiWeldeslassie I still don't understand the problem. The data is given, and you want the graph to show the *sum* of the values seen so far. This is what the plot currently shows. You can rescale your data by dividing it by the sum of the y-values (before plotting it). Or do you just want to relabel the y-axis to run from 0 to 1 instead of from 0 to sum-of-values?

Comment: @gernot Dear and Esteemed Gernot, the precise answer is I want to relabel the y-axis to run from 0 to 1. To succinctly explicate my specific interest, in the wealth analysis (in my research), I am going to identify household (individuals) as poor denoted by (1) and non-poor by zero. For this reason, it will not be logical (in my specific case) to have values greater than one in the y-axis. Thank you very much!

Comment: @HailaiWeldeslassie I have opened a new question for this remaining problem, see http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/350364/dynamic-re-labeling-of-y-axis

Comment: @HailaiWeldeslassie See [this answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/350371/110998) regarding the labeling of the y-axis. If I understood you correctly, this solves your problem.

Comment: @gernot YES! It solves my problem perfectly. Thanks so much dear! I am humbled and encouraged by your earthly and cordial assistance! GOD BLESS!