# Plot sum of distribution

Tags: tikz-pgf, plot

I have 1000 data points close to zero (absolute value < 0.1), adding up to 1. I want to plot their sums. I.e. if they followed a [normal distribution](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/7/74/Normal_Distribution_PDF.svg), I'd want to have an [S curve](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/c/ca/Normal_Distribution_CDF.svg) plotted.

I'm aware that I could compute the exact positions externally and then plot that, but there probably is a better solution.

Some of the values are negative. For them, the curve should go down a bit.

Comment: You can do https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/198397, just remove `jump mark left` and `discontinuous` from the `axis` options.

Comment: I take it they were already sorted.

Comment: @JohnKormylo I'm not sure what you mean. Of course, I got the data points in the order I want them to be used in. How would tikz be able to guess the order of the increments I want?

Comment: Never mind.  I thought you were dealing with random data, not sampled values of the Probability Density Function.