# Problems with pgfplots' compat (unsuitable tick labels)

Tags: pgfplots

I have a problem with `\pgfplotset{compat=1.11 and newer}` and the code of the accepted answer of the following question:
[Drawing cumulative distribution function for a discrete variable](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/198383/drawing-cumulative-distribution-function-for-a-discrete-variable)

If I use the code as it is, the picture looks like in the answer above, but I get:

```
Package pgfplots Warning: running in backwards compatibility mode (unsuitable t
ick labels; missing features). Consider writing \pgfplotsset{compat=1.16} into 
your preamble.
```

When I compile with `compat=1.10` everything is fine. But if I use a compat version {1.11 or newer} it leads to no error message in the log-file, but the figure is broken if the I don't start at (xmin=0,ymin=0), see

[image]

I'm using this code as template for cumulative distribution functions in an exercise pool for statistics and I'm not sure if it's a good idea to stay at version 1.10, since the exercise pool is still expanded. Is there a fix for this in newer versions? What are the *unsuitable tick labels*?

This is my first question in this forum and I'm a newbie in pgfplots, so please tell me if there is something missing or I did something wrong.

Thanks in advance!

Tommy

Comment: For me the result doesn't depend on chosen `compat` level. I am using PGFPlots v1.17 and TikZ v3.1.8b.

Comment: Thanks, for the reply. Two questions: (1) Do you get the warning in your log-file or are you able to compile it without the warning? (2) Just as verification. It's also possible when starting at negative x-range?

I'm just wondering because the problem appears on different Linux machines, when using pdflatex with texlive.

I'll check my pgfplots- and tikz-versions.

Comment: To (1): It is normal to get the `compat` warning, when not the current (used) version is stated at that key or if the key is missing. To (2): I have not clue, since I am not the author of the code ...