Piecewise function and label each jump on the left side
I have the following function which i want to plot:

and I have used this code:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
%plots
\usepackage{pgfplots, pgfplotstable}

%cdf graphing (see https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/198383/drawing-cumulative-distribution-function-for-a-discrete-variable)
\makeatletter
\long\def\ifnodedefined#1#2#3{%
    \@ifundefined{pgf@sh@ns@#1}{#3}{#2}%
}

\pgfplotsset{
    discontinuous/.style={
    scatter,
    scatter/@pre marker code/.code={
        \ifnodedefined{marker}{
            \pgfpointdiff{\pgfpointanchor{marker}{center}}%
             {\pgfpoint{0}{0}}%
             \ifdim\pgf@y>0pt
                \tikzset{options/.style={mark=*, fill=white}}
                \draw [densely dashed] (marker-|0,0) -- (0,0);
                \draw[options] plot coordinates {(marker-|0,0)};
;
             \else
                \tikzset{options/.style={mark=none}}
             \fi
        }{
            \tikzset{options/.style={mark=none}}        
        }
        \coordinate (marker) at (0,0);
       \begin{scope}[options, fill=blue]
    },
    scatter/@post marker code/.code={\end{scope}}
    }
}

\makeatother
\begin{document}
$$f(x) =
\begin{cases} 
0 & \text{if } x < -1, \\
\frac{1}{4} & \text{if } -1 \leq x < 1, \\
\frac{1}{2} & \text{if } 1 \leq x < 3, \\
1 & \text{if } x \geq 3.
\end{cases}$$
{\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    clip=false,
    jump mark left,
    ymin=0,ymax=1,
    xmin=0, xmax=4,
    every axis plot/.style={very thick},
    discontinuous,
    table/create on use/cumulative distribution/.style={
        create col/expr={\pgfmathaccuma + \thisrow{f(x)}}   
    }
]
\addplot [blue] table [y=cumulative distribution]{
x f(x)
-3 0
-2 0
-1 1/4
1 1/4
3 1/2
4 0
};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\par}



\end{document}

I get the following plot:

How can i fix the plot so that I can get something similar to the below?

With a few Teaks on your code. Added the \usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathreplacing} right after \usepackage{pgfplots}.
Here is your code with the additions I made
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}%plots
\usepackage{pgfplots, pgfplotstable}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathreplacing}
\makeatletter
\long\def\ifnodedefined#1#2#3{%
\@ifundefined{pgf@sh@ns@#1}{#3}{#2}%
}

    \pgfplotsset{
    discontinuous/.style={
        scatter,
        scatter/@pre marker code/.code={
            \ifnodedefined{marker}{
                \pgfpointdiff{\pgfpointanchor{marker}{center}}%
                {\pgfpoint{0}{0}}%
                \ifdim\pgf@y>0pt
                \tikzset{options/.style={mark=*, fill=white}}
                \draw [densely dashed] (marker-|0,0) -- (0,0);
                \draw[options] plot coordinates {(marker-|0,0)};
                ;
                \else
                \tikzset{options/.style={mark=none}}
                \fi
            }{
                \tikzset{options/.style={mark=none}}        
            }
                \coordinate (marker) at (0,0);
                \begin{scope}[options, fill=blue]
                },
                scatter/@post marker code/.code={\end{scope}}
    }
}

\makeatother
\begin{document}
    $$f(x) =
        \begin{cases} 
            0 & \text{if } x < -1, \\
            \frac{1}{4} & \text{if } -1 \leq x < 1, \\
            \frac{1}{2} & \text{if } 1 \leq x < 3, \\
            1 & \text{if } x \geq 3.
        \end{cases}$$
        {\centering
            \begin{tikzpicture}
                \begin{axis}[
                    clip=false,
                    axis lines=center,
                    jump mark left,
                    ymin=-0.5,ymax=1,
                    xmin=-3, xmax=4,
                    ylabel=\(f(x)\),
                    every axis plot/.style={very thick},
            discontinuous,
                table/create on use/cumulative distribution/.style={
                    create col/expr={\pgfmathaccuma + \thisrow{f(x)}}   
                }
                ]
                \addplot [very thick, red!70!black] table [y=cumulative distribution]{
                    x f(x)
                    -3 0
                    -2 0
                    -1 1/4
                    1 1/4
                    3 1/2
                    4 0
                };
            \end{axis}
            \node at (1.25,2.35) {\large \(C\)};
            \draw[very thick, decorate,decoration={brace}] (1.75,2) -- (1.75,2.85);
            \node at (3.25,3.35) {\large \(B\)};
            \draw[very thick, decorate,decoration={brace}] (3.75,2.9) -- (3.75,3.75);
            \node at (5,4.85) {\large \(A\)};
            \draw[very thick, decorate,decoration={brace}] (5.5,3.85) -- (5.5,5.75);
        \end{tikzpicture}
        \par}
\end{document}

Hope it helps you go on with your work!

Awesome, thank you!
