# Plotting cdf of a binomial distribution in tikz/pdfplot

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, plot, statistics

I have been trying to plot the cdf (commulative density function) of a binomial distribution - in the easiest way possible (is there a package i could use?)

I would be glad if somebody already stumbled across this problem and solved it for him/her and would share his thoughts on this.

I tried to implement RStudio plots but this doesn't quite give me the appeareance I aim for - because R-Plots can't be changed that much.

Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: Welcome to tex.sx! Maybe this could help you: [Probability density function of Uniform Distribution](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/117954/172164) (specifically the mention of pst-func in the comment)

Comment: Thank you. This seems to force me to put everything in "by hand". Is there no function, where one can write, say, plot(binom(...)) and you get the diagram?

Answer (score 0):

With XeLaTeX or LuaLaTeX you can compile (for example in OVerleaf):

```
% Requires XeLaTeX, LuaLaTeX, LaTeX compiler!!!!!
% Is not compatible with the pdfLaTeX compiler !!!!
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{pst-func}

\newcommand{\rightEndPlot}{6.8}
\newcommand{\BinomialN}{4}
\newcommand{\Binomialp}{0.5}
\begin{document}    

% See https://mirror.foobar.to/CTAN/graphics/pstricks/contrib/pst-func/doc/pst-func-doc.pdf
\psset{xunit=0.8cm,yunit=8cm}%
\begin{pspicture*}[showgrid=false](-1.5,-0.1)(\rightEndPlot,1.2)%
\psset{arrowscale=1.3,arrowinset=0.05,arrowlength=1.9,comma}%
\psaxes[labelFontSize=\scriptstyle,xticksize=0 1.07,yticksize=0 \rightEndPlot,tickcolor=gray!50,
Dy=0.1,dy=0.1,Dx=1,dx=1,Ox=0]{->}(0,0)(-0.9,0)(\rightEndPlot,1.1)
%\uput[-90](15.8,0){$z$}\uput[0](0,1.1){$P_{0,15}^{100}(Z=z)$}
\psBinomialF[linecolor=red,fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=yellow,barwidth=0.4,opacity=0.5,LineEndColorL=red,rightEnd=\rightEndPlot]{\BinomialN}{\Binomialp}
\end{pspicture*}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Note that this also works with pdfLaTeX if you load the package `auto-pst-pdf` and compile with shell-escape (which is the default in Overleaf).